# Adjectives regarding interfaces

Tags: terminology, reflection, x-rays

I'm studying X-Ray reflectivity at interfaces and the book I'm reading reads:

> ... The ideally flat, but graded interface, and the ideally sharp, but roughened interface, will be considered...

I'm struggling to understand the difference between the two kinds of interfaces mentioned. Please consider that English is not my first language. Exactly speaking, what do they mean with graded and sharp? How do these two surfaces differ from each other?

Answer (score 1):

This is ambiguous even for a native speaker of English.   Here's my best guess:

Ideally flat, but graded:  graded -- the interface is not discrete.  The transition from one side to the other happens gradually over some distance.  flat -- the interface is not curved;  the locus of points half-way between the two sides is a plane.

Sharp, but roughened:  sharp -- at any location the transition from one side to the other is discrete, a step function.  Roughened -- the transition region comprises many small peaks and valleys. The peaks and valleys are at random loacations, and their height and depth is random.

Here are some of the problems that I, a native English speaker, see.

- The usage of "graded" as I've defined it is not standard in this
  context, so my definition is a guess.  My definition is plausible,
  but since the usage is not standard it leaves open the possibility
  that my definition is wrong.  I would expect something like
  "continuous (or gradual) transition over some length".
- "Ideally sharp" can apply to a flat interface, but it could also apply to a bent interface.  Since it seems that he's trying to describe two contrasting situations, situations that are different only in the fact that one is a continuous transition and the other rough, I infer that he also takes "sharp" to mean "flat".

That this appears in a book raises concerns for me.  Ambiguities like these should be flagged and fixed in the editorial process.  That calls into question the quality of the publisher, and the quality of the text itself.

I hope this is not the book by David Attwood.  Attwood's book is very good.

Comment: Hi thanks for your effort. I wasn't able to understand the difference even upon further reading. I totally agree with you, books shouldn't give such sloppy definitions. The book is "Elements of modern X-ray physics" by Des McMorrow and Jens Als-Nielsen